Are "maps of sheaves" induced by morphisms of varieties?
A friend and I were trying to make sense of the definition of a morphism of (say affine or quasi-affine) varieties, as given by Hartshorne (p. 15-16):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two varieties, a morphism $\phi : X \to Y$ is a continuous map such that for any open set $V \subseteq Y$, and for every regular function $f : V \to k$, the function $f \circ \phi : \phi^{-1}(V) \to k$ is regular.

It seemed to us that what mattered most in this definition was the preservation of regular maps. In this spirit, we noticed that we could extract a "map" between the sheaves of regular functions over $X$ and $Y$, which "respect" the structure of the sheaves: if the sheaf of regular functions on $X$ is $\mathcal{O}_X$ and on $Y$ is $\mathcal{O}_Y$, then we have, for every open set $V$ in $Y$, a function
$$\phi_V : \mathcal{O}_Y(V) \to \mathcal{O}_X(\phi^{-1}(V)) \qquad \text{ by } \qquad f \mapsto f \circ \phi.$$
These maps "play nice" with the sheaves in the sense that they commute with the restriction maps:  if $W$ is an open subset of $V$, then
$$ |_{\phi^{-1}(W)} \circ \phi_V = \phi_W \circ |_W.$$
So, in a sense, as far the regular maps are concerned, a morphism of varieties is

A map $\phi^{-1}$ assigning open sets of $Y$ to open sets of $X$, which respects finite intersections and arbitrary unions (thank you @DanielSchepler for this correction), and
A family of maps $\phi_V : \mathcal{O}_Y(V) \to \mathcal{O}_X(\phi^{-1}(V))$, which respect the sheaf structure in the way laid out above.

Here's our question: given maps $\phi^{-1}$ and $\{ \phi_V \,\, | \,\, V \text{ open in } Y \}$ which obey all the requirements laid out above, does there exist a morphism $\phi$ between $X$ and $Y$ which induces these maps? Is this morphism unique? In other words to what degree does a morphism of varieties correspond to its action on the sheaf of regular functions?

Any such $\phi^{-1}$ coming from a morphism of schemes must also respect finite intersections and arbitrary unions (and it would follow from these conditions that also $\phi^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $\phi^{-1}(Y) = X$).  Otherwise, you seem to have rediscovered the category of ringed spaces (or in this case, ringed frames maybe?).  In particular, what you give in (2) is equivalent to a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}Y \to \phi* \mathcal{O}_X$.

@DanielSchepler Just having had a look at the wiki page for ringed spaces, it does seem remarkably close to what we came up with. It seems (according to Wikipedia at least) that a morphism of ringed spaces is required to also be a continuous map $f : X \to Y$. My question is, if we forget the map $f$ and only remember the action of $f^{-1}$, can we recover $f$? If I give you an $f^{-1}$ that respects finite intersections and arbitrary unions, and a morphism of sheaves (?) like (2), can I recover [an] $f$? At least in the case of affine varieties?

George, no. If you take the identity morphism from $A^2$ to itself and modify $\phi^{-1}(A^2-(0,0))$ to be $A^2,$ then that should be a counterexample I think. I will think about what happens when you add reasonable conditions as suggested by David and I will post an answer, Though I highly doubt you can recover the function

No. For a counter-example take $X=Y=\mathbb{A}^2.$ Then your open sets are $X,$ the empty set and complements of finitely many curves and points. Define $\phi^{-1}(U)$ to be $U$ in case of the empty set or if you have a curve running through $(0,0)$ in the complement of $U,$ and set $\phi^{-1}(U)=U\cup(0,0)$ otherwise, i.e. $\phi^{-1}$ fills in $(0,0)$ if it's missing in codimension $2.$
It is an exercise in Hartshorne to show that $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong\mathcal{O}(X-(0,0))$ with an isomorphism given by the restriction map. In fact you can show with basically the same argument that removing $(0,0)$ doesn't change the coordinate ring for any open subset of the plane. (Assuming that you know that all planar curves can be defined by a single equation.) So to define the morphism of sheaves you pull back functions through the restriction if $(0,0)$ was filled in and just leaves them fixed otherwise.
You can check that this has all the properties required. $\phi^{-1}$ is not induced by a morphism, or a function for that matter, because it doesn't respect the intersection property for arbitrary unions, as you can see from taking the intersection of $X-P$ for all points $P.$
You could add more stringent requirements, but I hope this makes it intuitive that you should not expect the kind of recovery of a function that you are looking for to be possible. The structure sheaf simply doesn't carry enough information because it can't really detect missing things of codimension at least $2.$
